# Processing Mandrill Inbound emails

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, iron-router, mandrill

I am having trouble processing inbound emails from mandrill with Meteorjs. I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to writing server side routes / API routes, so I hope I am not overlooking something insanely basic.
This is the iron-router route i have defined:
It gets the post call, creates a message object and inputs the object into my collection.

```
Router.route('/api/message/insert', function () {
  // NodeJS request object
  var request = this.request;


  request = JSON.parse(request.body.mandrill_events);
  console.log(request);
  var firstEmail = request[0];


  if(firstEmail.event == "inbound"){ // == used on purpose
    var email = firstEmail.msg.from_email;
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({"emails[0].address":email });
    var chatRoom = chatRooms.findOne({name:user_.id});
    var message = {
      content:firstEmail.msg.text,
      links:[],
      chatRoom:chatRoom._id,
      owner:user._id,
      ownerName:user.profile.name,
      ownerEmail:email,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    };
    chatMessages.insert(message);
  }
  // NodeJS  response object
  var response = this.response;


  this.response.end("chat message implemented");
}, {where: 'server'});
```

When I send test emails from the mandrill dashboard I get a positive response. Actually sending an email to the address that I registered with mandrill does nothing. I am having a hard time debugging this because I get no error code in my Modulus logs (also the console.log does nothing).

I have found this guide 
http://dev-blog.cloud-spinners.com/2014/03/sending-and-receiving-email-using.html
but i can't seem to see what I am doing fundamentally wrong here. I am aware that I need to process the email body further, but this is simply to get a "hello world" message into my database.

Answer (score 0):

iron-router doesn´t support multipart/form-data. I´ve used the following code with sendgrid.

```
var Busboy = Meteor.npmRequire("Busboy"),
    fs = Npm.require("fs"),
    os = Npm.require("os"),
    path = Npm.require("path");

Router.onBeforeAction(function (req, res, next) {
   var filenames = []; // Store filenames and then pass them to  request.
   req.body   = req.body  || {};


if (req.method === "POST") {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), filename);
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    filenames.push(saveTo);
    });

    busboy.on("field", function(fieldname, value) {


    req.body[fieldname] = value;

    });

   busboy.on("finish", function () {
  // Pass filenames to request
    req.filenames = filenames;
    next();
   });
}
  // Pass request to busboy
  req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

You can then get it in your route:

```
Router.route('inbound', {
 path: '/inbound/',
 where: 'server',
 action: function () {

 var body = this.request.body;
 console.log(body);
 ...
```

You will have to add the following package to use npm packages:meteor add meteorhacks:npm and add a packages.json file to the root of your project and add the following:

```
{ "busboy": "0.2.9"}
```